# Make Chrome read cross-domain cookies in iframe

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies, iframe

I have a main website (Site A) with a page that contains an iframe that shows information from another website (Site B) (ours as well).

The content inside the page on another website (Site B) is based on the cookies set on Site B. However, loading the cookie-filled site inside an iframe on a page on (Site A) shows no information. I can show simple text that does not rely on cookies but not any content that needs to access cookies.

Are there any Cookie attributes that I can set to make it work?

The content loads properly on Firefox just not on Chrome.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

- In Chrome, you should add the attribute `SameSite='None'` with `Secure`.
- In Firefox and Safari, you should disable the "prevent cross-site tracking cookies" in settings as well.